# Flutter 3.0 minkSdkVersion

Tags: flutter, gradle

I'm trying to locate `flutter.minkSdkVersion` in the Flutter project. I expected to find it in `flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle`, but it's not there.

Here's the content of the `flutter.gradle` file:

```
// Copyright 2014 The Flutter Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

// This file exists solely for the compatibility with projects that have
// not migrated to the declarative apply of the Flutter Gradle Plugin.

def pathToThisDirectory = buildscript.sourceFile.parentFile
apply from: "$pathToThisDirectory/src/main/groovy/flutter.groovy"
```

Does anyone know where I can find `flutter.minkSdkVersion`?

---

I tried looking for other answers with no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is located at:

`your_flutter_path/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/src/main/groovy/flutter.groovy`

You can change the `minSdkVersion`